# Strange order by in MySQL: order on field A plus duplicate-status from field B

Tags: mysql

I need to have a very weird ORDER BY. Let's say I have a table like:

```
pkey   id2
1      8
2      3
3      12
4      8
5      7
6      8
7      3
8      1
```

I need to SELECT in the following order:
Follow pkey EXCEPT when id2 has duplicates. Then do FIRST the duplicates.

So the ORDER BY should give the following result:

```
pkey   id2
1      8
4      8
6      8
2      3
7      3
3      12
5      7
8      1
```

I have no clue where to start. GROUP BY? Subqueries? Anyone any ideas? Or should I go php on this? I prefer to do it in MySQL.

Comment: In my opinion this task would be much harder to accomplish by mysql. But not that difficult with php

Comment: GROUP BY to find min(pkey) for each id2, then join that to the original and order by the min and then the pkey.

Comment: Rumesh you are right; but I want, if possible, to keep the php as it is right now, for company reasons.

Comment: UUeerdo: THANK YOU, that is it. Do you want the credits? Just make an answer, I will make it the official solution.  This does it: `SELECT a.*
FROM table a
LEFT  JOIN (SELECT id2, MIN(pkey) as minId FROM table b GROUP BY id2) b
    ON a.id2 = b.id2 
ORDER BY minId, pkey, id`

Actually quite simple!

Comment: LEFT JOIN could be just JOIN

Comment: If you had read, I wanted to give the solver a change to get the credits, yet not lure people looking for unsolved questions. Sometimes people have good reasons to do what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my succinct hint, Roemer came up with this solution:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table a 
     JOIN 
     (SELECT id2, MIN(pkey) as minId FROM table b GROUP BY id2) b 
     USING (id2) 
ORDER BY minId, pkey, id
```

It uses an aggregating subquery to find the first pkey for each id2, and uses those pkey values in the outer query to control ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I'd join the query on an aggregate query that counts the number of duplicate `id2`s each `pkey` has. Since multiple `pkey`s can have the same number of associated `id2`s, I'd throw in the minimal `pkey` just to make sure that you get all the rows with the same `pkey` together:

```
SELECT   a.pkey, a.id2
FROM     mytable a
JOIN     (SELECT   id2, COUNT(*) AS cnt, MIN(pkey) AS mpkey
          FROM     mytable
          GROUP BY id2) ON a.id2 = b.id2
ORDER BY cnt DESC, mpkey ASC, a.pkey ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Uueerdo gave the answer in a comment. I still want to give him credits, but people get confused, so I post this answer anyway, but I invite Uueerdo to post the answer so I can mark his answer as the proper one.

Anyway, the solution:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM table a 
     JOIN 
     (SELECT id2, MIN(pkey) as minId FROM table b GROUP BY id2) b 
     USING (id2) 
ORDER BY minId, pkey, id
```

Comment: I didn't have the motivation to make a well formed answer, and don't now either, so just mark your answer here as the accepted one; I believe that is allowed.

Comment: I will tomorrow. The system won;t let me today. Don;t know why. But again: thanks!

Comment: (And you could have copied mine ;) . (Still can. Still can't accept my own answer)

Comment: Just in time ;)